# ipfs.add TypeError: AbortController constructor: 'new' is required

Tags: web3js, react, ipfs

I am using latest version `"ipfs-http-client": "^48.2.2"`

```
<form onSubmit={ async (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    try{
                        const postResponse = await ipfs.add(buffer) 
                        console.log("postResponse", postResponse);
                    } catch(e){
                        console.log("Error: ", e)
                    }
}} >
```

The `buffer` variable is in this format (from the console): `Uint8Array(951674) [ 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, … ]`

I am getting `TypeError: AbortController constructor: 'new' is required` after pressing submit.

Other info:

- using Ganache, VSCode, solc 0.8.0, web3 1.0+
- this is a snippet from a react component

**EDIT:** I am not using AbortController anywhere in the code. The error does not provide line numbers from my code (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in an [issue](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/3509) I opened.